# Setting up Database - Integration Test with Jasmine/Jest

Tags: jasmine, jestjs

I have a bunch of integration tests using Jest (which uses Jasmine)

```
describe('DB User', async () => {
  beforeEach(setup)
  afterEach(teardown)
})
```

In my `setup` and `teardown` methods, I am connecting+clearing database and disconnecting from it, respectively.

My problem now is testing them asynchronously, as the db can get cleared while other tests are running. What is the recommended way to solve this?

I cannot mock the db as I am doing a lot of direct queries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just checked out Objection.js (Javascript ORM). In their integration tests, it's basically creating and keeping one database session and running the tests synchronously.

[Objection Integration Test](https://github.com/Vincit/objection.js/blob/master/tests/integration/index.js)

Basically, in pseudocode:

```
var session = initialize()

describe(knexConfig.client, function () {
  before(function () {
    return session.clearDb();
  });

  after(function () {
    // destroy db connection
    return session.destroy();
  });

  // individual tests
  require('./test')(session)
});
```

Will wait if there are better answers

Comment: great, I can use this pattern. I'm just wondering if it's still the way to go?